# Sorting in GraphQL by ID

Tags: node.js, graph, next.js, react-apollo, strapi

I downloaded one simple tutorial code.
But as I am playing with it I couldn't figure out how can I sort for example by id in graphql.

This is query.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const Query = ({ children, query, id }) => {
  console.log(id);
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(query, {
    variables: { id: parseInt(id) }
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>;
  return children({ data });
};

export default Query;
```

Articles.js

```
    import gql from "graphql-tag";

    const ARTICLES_QUERY = gql`

  query Articles {
    articles(limit: 10) {
      id
      title
      category {
        id
        name
      }
      Image
    }
  }
`;

export default ARTICLES_QUERY;
```

And then calling it using one componnent.

```
  <Query query={ARTICLES_QUERY}>
    {({ data: { articles } }) => {
      return <Articles articles={articles} />;
    }}
  </Query>
```

I was able to limit number of results to 10 as you can see in code `articles(limit: 10)` but i cant figure out how can i see only last 10 items. (now its first 10). Thank for any help.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do sorting, filtering, pagination, etc. In GraphQL. Whether you can sort the results and how to do so depends on the GraphQL service you're querying. The server's GraphiQL or GraphQL Playground interface would be a good starting point.

Comment: Can you post the link to the graphql service you are using? If you are using a local server, go to the playground, open the docs and send a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update the sort on the ID to fetch from the end

```js
query Articles {
    articles(limit: 10, sort: "id:desc") {
      id
      title
      category {
        id
        name
      }
      Image
    }
  }
```